# PHP superscript

Tags: php, html, text, replace, superscript

Is there any way that  I can get o identify characters like(trademark, superscripts, numbers) from text or text file(but these characters are't in HTML code) and replace them using php

Example:

Get from text: ™ replace with PHP: (TM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just parse your strings with `str_replace`.

Note that `str_replace` can use arrays, so you can replace multiple strings at once:

```
$text = "Text™®";
$text = str_replace(['™', '®'], ['(TM)', '(R)'], $text);
print $text;
```